# Web filtering choices

Tags: traffic-filtering

I'm in the process of starting up my own business and I would like to know when it comes to web content filtering what are my options? I can honestly admit I'm looking for a more user friendly system due to my limited computer experience. Currently i foresee the use of no more than three dozen PC towers under a single network using Windows 8 as an OS system. I was advised that Web Content Filter might be a good place to start,but as I have said before this is new territory for me. Any advise s much welcomed

Comment: This is a rather broad question. It's not exactly clear what you mean. It depends on your network setup, what services do you want to implement in your network, etc.. Are you talking about end-user clients or servers, are you offering services that must be reachable from the internet, what do you want to filter? Are you looking for a proxy server or something what is called "Unified Threat Management" these days? Please rephrase your question and be more specific if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

This can be done in software.

See: [Websense](http://www.websense.com/content/home.aspx)

This can be done in hardware.

See: [Barracuda Web Filter](https://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/spyware_overview.php)

This can be done in "The Cloud".

See: [Barracuda Web Security Flex](https://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/web_security_flex_overview.php)

Software is nice because it's quicker to download/test. Hardware is nice in that it doesn't require config on the individual computers. Cloud is nice because it doesn't require equipment. Any of these would work.

For more detailed product discussion, check the [Spiceworks community forums](http://community.spiceworks.com/). Quite a few education IT professionals use the site, and web filtering is a key function in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/web-filtering)?